# Can you determine whether the logarithm is an integer without computing it?

Tags: logarithms, integers

Given a logarithm with an arbitrary base, can we determine whether it is going to be an integer or not without evaluating it?

Comment: What does it mean for a logarithm to be an integer?  What numbers have base $10$ logs that are integers?

Comment: lg(10) = 1 which is an integer.

Comment: How is $\log_a(x)=n$ defined? Consider $a=e$ and the exponential, for example.

Comment: Umm... ln(e) = 1 which is an integer? I don't understand what's so confusing about the question.

Comment: I don't understand what's so confusing about the answer. What is the definition of $\log_a$?

Comment: The commenters aren't confused, the questions are hints. What have you tried?

Comment: Idk, here's the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm. I've tried googling I guess.

Comment: Yes.  Let the prime factorization of $a$ be given by $$\prod_{i=1}^r (p_i)^{a_i}.$$  Let the prime factorization of $n$ be given by $$\prod_{i=1}^s (p_i)^{b_i}.$$  Then, $\log_a(n) = k$ will be an integer if and only if the following two conditions are met:  [1] $r = s$.  [2] There exists a positive integer $m$ such that for all $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,r\}$ you have that $a_i \times m = b_i.$

Comment: Factorization seems more computationally intensive then calculating the log itself though. Thanks a lot, still.

Comment: Instead of googling, just think about it. Can you tell whether $\log_{10}100000$ is an integer?

Comment: You are assuming that if the computer (or calculator) reports that the logarithm is an integer, that the logarithm is an integer.  Instead, it could well be that the logarithm is being reported as an integer, even though it is (instead) microscopically close to being an integer, because of rounding error.

Comment: Hint: can you find the floor and ceiling of $\log_b a$ without computing the exact log?

Comment: I can tell that lg(1000...) is an integer because it's easy for me to tell that 1000... = 10^n, but if I have base 85416958456 log of some other monstrosity I can't tell just by glancing at it, I need a formula.

It's true that calculator might be giving me a rounding error, but it's easy to check if that's the case.

Comment: Floor would be b^n < a and ceiling would be b^m > a where m = n + 1. But finding n requires trial and error or calculating the log and flooring it, neither being useful I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to determining if $a$ is a perfect $b$th power.  Therefore just divide $a$ by $b$ until you either get 1 or a non integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can, by using $p$-adics. I demonstrate for the case of an odd base, for which you can always use $p=2$. My example will be $\log_3243$, which I "don't know" will equal $5$.

Begin by identifying in what range of integers the logarithm could be. In a computer where numbers are represented in base 2, $3$ will have two bits and $243$ will have eight. Thus $2^1<3<2^2$ and $2^7<243<2^8$, from which $7/2<\log_3243<8/1$ or, if the logarithm is to be an integer,

$4\le\log_3243\le7.$

Then if we were to render the logarithm $\bmod 2^2=4$ using $2$-adics, we could determine a candidate integer value against which we can check by exponentiation.

In $2$-adics, logarithms of odd numbers can be determined if and only if the arguments are one greater than a multiple of $4$, but neither $3$ nor $243$ is so. We overcome this by changing signs so that we are rendering $2$-adically $\log_{-3}(-243)$. From the signs we know the result will be odd.

Next we take the differences of our arguments from $+1$ and compare the largest power of $2$ that divides each. Thus $(-3)-1=-4$ and $(-243)-1=-244$, both of which have $4$ as the largest power-of-2 factor. Since the powers of $2$ are the same, this result is consistent with an odd integer logarithm. An even integer logarithm would require the base to be divisible by a smaller power of $2$ than the number whose logarithm is taken.

So we know that $\log_{-3}(-243)$ will be an odd integer in $2$-adics, and now we are to determine its residue $\bmod 4$. To do this we apply the Maclaurin series for the natural logarithm, intending to divide $\ln(-243)$ by $\ln(-3)$. (Remember, we are working in $p$-adics, not real numbers. Get used to logarithms with negative numbers!) There is one final catch: since $4$ divides $(-3)-1$ as noted above, it's logarithm will have two nonsignificant terminal zeroes so to get a result $\bmod 4$ after dividing the natural logarithms, we have to work the natural logarithms $\bmod 16$.

With that we are ready to go. First, the logarithm of $-3$:

$\ln(1-4)=-4-\dfrac{4^2}2-\dfrac{4^3}3-\dfrac{4^4}4-...$

$=-4-8-\dfrac{64}3-64-...$

$\equiv-4-8\equiv4\bmod16$

(Terms beyond the fourth power will all be multiples of $2^4$ so the series terminates $\bmod 16$.)

Next do $\ln(-243)$. But we note that $-243\equiv(-3)\bmod16$ so modulo $16$, the series is the same as the one above.

So, we have

$(\ln(-3))(\log_{-3}(-243))=\ln(-243)$

$4(\log_{-3}(-243))\equiv4\bmod16$

$\log_{-3}(-243)\equiv1\bmod4$

In $2$-adics this means our logarithm would end with $...01$, which will be true whether the logarithm is a natural integer or not. Now, given our earlier bound $4\le\log_3243\le7$, if the logarithm *were* a natural integer it would have to be $5$. So we check whether $3^5$ is in fact $243$, and... voilà!