# Calculating $\log_5(.008)$ and $\sin(75)+\sin(120)-\cos(150)+\cos(165)$ by hand

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

Calculating $\log_5(.008)$ and $\sin(75)+\sin(120)-\cos(150)+\cos(165)$ by hand

Sorry if these seems like two different questions, I figured the theme was simiar enough.

I'm  helping somebody prepare for a test on which they are not allowed to use a calculator. The review had questions like the two above.

$log_5(.008)y \iff 5^y=.008$

How would you solve this by hand? I mean, the answer is $y=-3$ which is nice, but in theory $y$ could be any real number. I suppose we could just hope the answer is nice an do long division... $\frac{1}{5^2}$ and then $\frac{1}{5^3}$ etc.

And then for the trig question, I'm not seeing any useful trig identies to relate these angles back to something to one of the commonly known angles i.e. angles with reference angle $0,\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: The log one can be done by inspection .  $.008=\frac 8{1000}=\frac 1
{125}$  The trig one appears to require $\sin (15), \cos (15)$ which you can get from half angle formulas

Comment: Seeing a decimal, one might think to note that $5^{-1} = 0.2$.

Comment: $ \cos 165º \ = \ −\cos(180º−165º) \ \ , \ \ \sin 75ª \ = \ \cos(90º−75º) \ \  . $ The other trig values are ones students are expected to know, and  $ \ \sin 120º \ = \ \sin(180º−120º)  \ \ , \ \  -\cos 150º \ = \   \cos(180º−150º) \ \  = \ \ \sin(90º−30º) \ \  . $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert $0.008$ into a  fraction  : $\frac{8}{1000} = \frac{1}{125}$. If you can now recognize that $125 = 5^3$ then you're done.

For the trig question, all of the numbers are multiples of $15$, and you know $\sin(45^\circ), \sin(30^\circ), \cos(45^\circ), \cos(30^\circ)$, and then apply the sum and difference formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Expanding on lulu's hint, $$\log_{5} .008 \Rightarrow \log_{5} \frac {8}{1000} \Rightarrow \log_{5} \frac {1}{125} \Rightarrow \log_{5} \frac {1}{5^3} $$ Can you finish?
2. $\sin 120^{\circ}$ and $\cos 150^{\circ}$ are easy enough to find (in fact, they will be the same value with opposite signs) but $\sin 75^{\circ} = \sin \frac {150^{\circ}}{2}$ and $\cos 165^{\circ} = \cos \frac {330^{\circ}}{2}$ (and yet again, they will be the same value with opposite signs).

EDIT: Note that $\cos 165^{\circ} = \sin (-75)^{\circ} = -\sin 75^{\circ}$, so you may not need the half-angle formulas after all.  Furthermore, $\sin 120^{\circ} = \sin 60^{\circ}$ and $-\cos 150^{\circ} = -\sin (-60^{\circ}) = +\sin 60^{\circ}$.  Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4384111/248217) a method is described using $p$-adics to identify when a logarithm is an integer. First you count bits in a computer (binary) representation of each number, getting a range of candidate integers. Then you use $p$-adics to find the single candidate in this range, which can be checked.

Applying it to the problem of getting the logarithm of 125 to base 5:

1. the number $5$ has three bits in binary, while $125$ has seven. Thus $\log_5(125)$ must lie strictly between $(7-1)/3=2$ and $7/(3-1)=3.5.$
2. The only integer in this range is $3$, so in this case we skip all the $p$-adic calculations and immediately check whether $5^3=125.$

Comment: Wow, fancy!!!!!!